# Is make_pair used in vector init is wrong?

Tags: c++

I init a vector like this:

```
vector<pair<float,int>> A(make_pair(1.0,0),10);
```

and error occured:

```
error:no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<float, int> >::vector(std::pair<float, int>, int)’
```

so how to init vector<pair> struct? I want init this with N same pairs, should i use push_back?

Comment: `1.0` isn't a`float`.  But moreso, the order of the parameters is *quantity* of elements, then *value* of those elements.

Comment: @Eljay "*`1.0` isn't a float*" - true, it is a `double` instead. `1.0f` is a `float`, though.

Answer (score 6):

You have a `vector` of `pair`s. To construct one with ten pairs, you need to specify the **amount first, then the initial values**. In other words: *"How much of what"*:

```
vector<pair<float, int>> A(10, make_pair(1.0f, 0));
```